# Indexed data is not being returned using range index queries

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

We are facing a weird issue on our ML databases. Range indexed data is not getting fetched using range queries. However, if we use element value queries, we get this data.

Also, if we re-insert the documents containing this range indexed data, we do get it using the range queries. Re-indexing the database fixes the issue too. This suggests missed indexes.

We are facing such issues quite frequently, and it's affecting the end users of our services. What could be the reason behind this anomaly?

I am using MarkLogic version 8.0-3.2

Comment: When you see this anomaly is the database per chance reindexing? Could it be that the database has not yet indexed the elements when you perform the first range query?

Comment: @ElijahBernstein-Cooper, I don't think that's the case as this is happening with old XML files in the database. Also, automatic re-indexing is enabled.

Comment: This is quite peculiar. By chance, are you using CPF or triggers? It's possible those may be interfering with the content of your data in unexpected ways. I would check those carefully if so. Please consider opening a ticket with MarkLogic Support.

Comment: We are not using CPF and triggers. Going to open a support request with MarkLogic soon.

Comment: Could you also confirm the re-indexer throttle settings, Data Size, and number of range-indexes?